# rdivison by logical array in Matlab - Not sure about behaviour

Tags: arrays, matlab, division

In Matlab I have this

```
X = double(1./(1+exp(-P)) > rand(size(P)))
```

Where P is a 100x100 matrix.
I seem to be unable to understand what is going on after the operation is complete. The values stored in X are 0's and 1's.

For the following statement

```
(1+exp(-P)) > rand(size(P))
```

I endup with a logical array. In one particular case, all values are 1's.  But once the element-wise division is induced

```
1./(1+exp(-P)) > rand(size(P))
```

I end up with 1's and 0's. What I do not understand is that the logical array of all 1's  produces 1's and 0's after division

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the division is evaluated *before* the `>` comparison (more on operator precedence [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html)). The way that you have it written, it compares `1 ./ (1 + exp(-P))` to `rand(size(P))` using `>` and will return `true` where the first expression is larger than a random number.

I'm assuming that you meant something like the following (notice the parentheses around the denominator)

```
1 ./ ((1+exp(-P)) > rand(size(P)))
```

That being said, this still doesn't really make sense because `1 + exp(-P)` is *always* going to be greater than `1` (the max value of `rand`) so this should always yield all `1`'s.

As a side-note, just because an array is all 1's and 0's does not mean that it's logical, you have to confirm that using `class`.

```
class(var)
%   logical
```

Comment: That was a good explanation. Thanks. I now understand what was going on.